# Postman mock services not working on flutter android app release

Tags: android, flutter, mocking, postman, backend

I am using postman for a mock api services to test back-end requests on a flutter android app, it works in debug mode however when I create an app release it doesn't work, why is that?

Comment: Any code, logs, stacktrace, anything?

Comment: It shows this error whenever I try a request : SocketException: Failed host lookup: OS error: No address associated with hostname, errno=7
However it works fine in debug mode as I said

Comment: `No address associated with hostname` should be your go-to issue. The app cannot find the server that you have added to mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the solution was simply by adding this to AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```